# A function is analytic in a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I know that a function is analytic if it satisfies the Cauchy Riemann rules but how can my professor can tell without doing any kind of calculation that a function is analytic in a circle?
As an example: $f(z): \frac{\sin(hz)}{z^3}$ is analytic in $C:||z-2||=1$ therefore the integral of f in C is zero.

Comment: Hint: Are you familiar with the quotient rule in calculus? This also holds true for complex differentiation.

Comment: Yes but i cant see where i would use that here

Comment: You should have also seen some proposition which tells you that compositions of analytic functions are also analytic (stated in a more proper way).

Comment: oh ok i got it thanks